# return system date on checkbox check jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am somewhat a beginner to jquery.  I am having trouble creating a function to fill a textbox with the current date when a checkbox is clicked.  I have the routine working on its own, but i would like to wrap it in a function so i can call it multiple times on the page.  I have included the code here as well as a jsfiddle link

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/pa7vn/)

html:

```
 <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Label8">Start Date:</span>

        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$startdateSrvcTXT" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_startdateSrvcTXT" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled" />

        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Label11">Check to Start</span>

        <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_StartFillCHK" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$StartFillCHK" />
```

javascript:

```
/*----This works------
$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_StartFillCHK').click(function () {

                if (this.checked) {

                    var myDate = new Date();

                    var prettyDate = (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + myDate.getDate() + '.' +

myDate.getFullYear();

                    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_startdateSrvcTXT').val(prettyDate);

                } else { //if not checked

                    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_startdateSrvcTXT').val('');

                }

            });

*/

//this doesnt
function fillclick(txtid,checkid){
$("'" + checkid + "'").click(function () {

                if (this.checked) {

                    var myDate = new Date();

                    var prettyDate = (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + myDate.getDate() + '.' +

myDate.getFullYear();

                    $("'" + txtid + "'").val(prettyDate);

                } else { //if not checked

                    $("'" + txtid + "'").val('');

                }

            });
}

fillclick("#ContentPlaceHolder1_startdateSrvcTXT","#ContentPlaceHolder1_StartFillCHK");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're querying by ID; you need to use `#` selectors:

```
$("#" + checkid).click
```

and

```
$("#" + txtid).val
```

Edit: You're already using them. There's no need to quote anything, they're already strings:

```
$(checkid).click
```

and

```
$(txtid).val
```

.

Comment: that works thanks.  I thought that by passing the string parameter with # selector as part of the string that would work, but apparently not

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: Right, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

```
function fillclick(txtid,checkid){
      $("#" + checkid).click(function () {

                if (this.checked) {

                    var myDate = new Date();

                    var prettyDate = (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + myDate.getDate() + '.' + myDate.getFullYear();

                    $("#" + txtid).val(prettyDate);

                } else { //if not checked

                    $("#" + txtid).val('');

                }

            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't say anything about the function to get the current time. I will try to help you to do the next things.
You have a checkbox and a text box like these:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ch1" name="ch1" />
<input type="text" id="current_time" name="current_time">
```

Now, use this code to do what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var myTime = getTime(); // getTime() is your own function to get the current time.
   if ($('#ch1').is(':checked')) {
      $('#current_time').val(myTime);
   }
});
```

I hope I could help you.